# How do I create png button animation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, button, png

I'm a graphic designer in Portugal, used to work with code everyday, like css, html and a bit javascript and php. I am currently developing an interactive logo button, but it has to be PNG to look the way I want. This is the javascript code on html (image is hosted in my website):

I want to create a mouseclick start and stop on last/first frame, not a infinite loop like this, and reversed animation after click to open/close. Basically, the lock and unlock of the padlock.

The point of this animation is to open a menu nav-bar under the logo. Can you help me?

My code:

```js
var cSpeed = 5;
var cWidth = 200;
var cHeight = 145;
var cTotalFrames = 7;
var cFrameWidth = 200;
var cImageSrc = 'https://www.studiogo.net/sprites.png';

var cImageTimeout = false;
var cIndex = 0;
var cXpos = 0;
var SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 0;

function startAnimation() {

  document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + cImageSrc + ')';
  document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.width = cWidth + 'px';
  document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.height = cHeight + 'px';

  //FPS = Math.round(100/(maxSpeed+2-speed));
  FPS = Math.round(100 / cSpeed);
  SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1 / FPS;

  setTimeout('continueAnimation()', SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES / 1000);

}

function continueAnimation() {

  cXpos += cFrameWidth;
  //increase the index so we know which frame of our animation we are currently on
  cIndex += 1;

  //if our cIndex is higher than our total number of frames, we're at the end and should restart
  if (cIndex >= cTotalFrames) {
    cXpos = 0;
    cIndex = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.backgroundPosition = (-cXpos) + 'px 0';

  setTimeout('continueAnimation()', SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES * 1000);
}

function imageLoader(s, fun) //Pre-loads the sprites image
  {
    clearTimeout(cImageTimeout);
    cImageTimeout = 0;
    genImage = new Image();
    genImage.onload = function() {
      cImageTimeout = setTimeout(fun, 0)
    };
    genImage.onerror = new Function('alert(\'Could not load the image\')');
    genImage.src = s;
  }

//The following code starts the animation
new imageLoader(cImageSrc, 'startAnimation()');
```

```html
<div id="loaderImage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see if this is what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".lock").click(function () {
    var $self = $(this);

    if ($self.hasClass("closed")) {
      $self.removeClass("close");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $self.addClass("open").removeClass("closed");
      }, 100);
    } else {
      $self.removeClass("open");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $self.addClass("close").addClass("closed");
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.lock {
  background-image: url('https://www.studiogo.net/sprites.png');
  width: 200px;
  height: 145px;
  background-position: 0 center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.closed {
  background-position: -1200px center;
}

div.close {
  animation: close-animation 300ms steps(6, start); // 1200px / 200px = 6
}

div.open {
  animation: close-animation 300ms steps(6, end); // 1200px / 200px = 6
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes close-animation {
  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }
  
  to {
    background-position: -1200px center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lock closed">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Felipeptcho , the code doensnt work on my website idk why :( , can you find out why? check here: www.studiogo.net  .. Thank you :3

Comment: Diogo Melo, have you fixed it? It's working for me. :)

Comment: Yes i did, thanks :) working perfectly thanks to you <3

Comment: Great! I'm glad for that! :)

Comment: Felipe, i guess i need your help again.. how can i move a div that has "<div class="lock closed"></div>" inside it moving to 20% top css when the lock is open??.. i still can not costumize the code you solve for me :(...

Comment: Maybe u can help me, im trying to do a login but for that, when the lock is clicked it needs to go 20 % top. Thanks for your time, ure awesome :)

Comment: Check my website: www.studiogo.net , the div im talking about is the div with the class:  gocenteralign

Comment: @DiogoMelo Change `$self.addClass("open").removeClass("closed");` to `$self.addClass("open").removeClass("closed").parent().css("top", "20%");` and `$self.addClass("close").addClass("closed");` to `$self.addClass("close").addClass("closed").parent().css("top", "50%");`. Sorry for the delay.